# How to use JGit to push changes to remote with OAuth access token

Tags: java, jgit

I am able to push to remote with this piece of code

```
return git.push().setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(user, password)).setRemote("origin").call();
```

I also am able to get oauth access token with all necessary scopes. How do I push with access token?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass a `UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider` with the token as its user name.

```
String remoteUrl = "https://${token}@github.com/user/repo.git";
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("${token}", "");
git.push().setRemote(remoteUrl).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```

The above can at least be used to authenticate with a GitHub repository. Though, I can't say if this scheme works generally.

Comment: turns out it is sufficient to include the token in the credentials provider. There is no need to reformat repository url. But anyways it works.

Comment: @user1745356 Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I also have similar question which is using `jgit` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380719/how-to-use-jgit-to-clone-the-existing-repositories-to-new-github-instance). If possible, can you help me out? Started learning `jgit` today so got stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Did anyone test this for `git push`? I get back just `not authorized` when trying to push a tag I created. Also in the github URL do you need to substitute the `user/repo.git` part with the actual name/owner of the repo?

Comment: @sydd yes, this works for the `PushCommand` and yes you need to supply the actual username/repo.

Comment: This approach is not working for bitbucket. Any idea on how to connect to bitbucket using token?

Answer (score 0):

Using the GitHub Action token within a GitHub Actions step accordingly as username like this: `new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("${{ github.token }}", "")` - this did **NOT** succeed! - It did end up with authorization failing.

I had to use the repositories owner name as user and the github action token as password like `new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("${{ github.repository_owner }}", "${{ github.token }}")` - that worked.

**Note:** In actual JAVA code you will have to pass `${{ github.repository_owner }}` and `${{ github.token }}` from outside like e.g. java -D system properties since the `UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider` constructor will not resolve the value of these github action variables.