# How to use jgit to clone the existing repositories to new github instance?

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

We have two separate GitHub instance running. One GitHub instance is `https://github.dev.host.com` and other github instance is `https://github.host.com`. I have various repositories in `https://github.dev.host.com` which I need to migrate to this new github instance `https://github.host.com`.

I am using JGit as I am working with Java. For example - Below are the repositories that are present in `https://github.dev.host.com` instance which I need to migrate to new github instance `https://github.host.com`

```
https://github.dev.host.com/Database/ClientService
https://github.dev.host.com/Database/Interest
```

As I am using JGit so I want to create these two above repositories in my new  GitHub instance through Java code. And after running my Java code, I should see all the above respositories and all its branches and contents from my `https://github.dev.host.com` into my new Github instance `https://github.host.com` as shown something like below -

```
https://github.host.com/Database/ClientService
https://github.host.com/Database/Interest
```

I just need to iterate the all the repositories list which I have in my old github instance and create those if they don't exit with all its contents and branches in my new github instance. And if they already exists, then overwrite all the changes from old to new instance.

Is this possible to do this using JGit? I also have `https` access to my both the github instances through my username and password.

As of now I can only do basic stuff as shown below which I learnt going through the tutorial.

```
public class CreateNewRepository {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // prepare a new folder
        File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
        localPath.delete();

        // create the directory
        Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(localPath, ".git"));
        repository.create();

        System.out.println("Having repository: " + repository.getDirectory());

        repository.close();

        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(localPath);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be of great help as this is my first time working with JGit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable approach would be to clone the repositoy from the *source* server to a temporary location and from there push it to the *destination* server.

You can clone a repository with JGit like this:

```
Git.cloneRepository()
  .setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "user", "password" ) );
  .setURI( remoteRepoUrl )
  .setDirectory( localDirectory )
  .setCloneAllBranches( true )
  .call();
```

To transfer the just cloned repositoy to the destination, you have to create a repository on the destination server first. Neither JGit nor Git support this step. GitHub offers a REST API that lets you [create repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/). The [developer pages](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) also list the language bindings that are available for this API with Java among them.

Once the (empty) repository is there, you can push from the temporary copy to the remote:

```
  Git git = Git.open( localDirectory );
  git.push()
    .setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "user",  "password" ) );
    .setRemote( newRemoteRepoUrl )
    .setForce( true )
    .setPushAll()
    .setPushTags()
    .call()
```

More information about authentication can be found [here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/)

Note that if the source repository contains tags, these have to be fetched into the temporary repository separately after cloning.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I have got the idea what I need to do. So I guess best approach is, to clone the above two repositories to a temporary location and then from there push it to destination server which is my new github instance? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @david Yes, that's what my answer suggests

Comment: Sure understood. One more thing, In your second code snippet which is pushing the `localDirectory` changes to the destination. In my case that destination is to this new github instance `https://github.host.com` but how that second code snippet will know that I need to push the `localDirectory` changes to that new github instance?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't quite understand the question. The directory given to `Git.open()` specifies the repository. The `git` variable acts like a factory for commands and its  `push()` method returns a `PushCommand` that operates on `localRepository`. You can find more about accessing repostories with JGit [here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/).

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear earlier. What I mean to say is - I have one repository in this github instance `https://github.dev.host.com` which I need to migrate to this new Github instance `https://github.host.com`. So I am cloning the repository from my first github instance with your first code snippet but in your second code snippet, how does it know that I need to push that localDirectory changes to my new  github instance (`https://github.host.com`). I have updated the question with the code I have to make it more  clear what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I overlooked that the remote wasn't specified. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. One last thing, if the localDirectory already exists, then as of now it gives an exception `Destination path "ClientService" already exists and is not an empty directory`. Is there any way we can force the clone to happen in the existing directory?

Comment: No, why don't you just delete the directory contents before cloning?

Comment: Yeah that was my other option if the  force cloning didn't work.

Comment: I have one more basic question. Suppose I have two branch (master and staging) in `github.dev.host.com` then with the above approach it will only push master branch from `github.dev.host.com` to `github.host.com` under the same repository. Right? Is there any way it can push all the branches of repository from one github to another github in my case?

Comment: I have amended the answer. The `PushCommand` already pushed all branches (using `setPushAll()`). With `setCloneAllBranches( true )`, the `CloneCommand` should now clone all branches from the source repository.

Comment: Thanks  for the help. Very well understood now. Appreciated your help.